# ROSJOY settings

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm running on Ubuntu 12.04 and hydro,

When using a joystick with my computer I see it assigned as js1. With nothing plugged into my computer, when I run the command  `ls /dev/input/'` there is a js0 listed, I don't know what it is.
Anyway, when I use `rosrun joy joy_node` I get an error

```
[ERROR] [1407853001.741326266]: [registerPublisher] Failed to contact master at [localhost:11311].  Retrying...
```

unless I first do

```
rosparam set joy_node/dev "/dev/input/js1"
```

but I need to do this every time I use ROS. Is there a way to save the setting or something like that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189843/rosjoy-settings/) by [dshimano](https://answers.ros.org/users/19862/dshimano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 129 on 2014-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can make a launch file and set that as the port you want to use.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1